# Apple Mail (MacBook Air) not receiving emails

Tags: email

An email account is not authenticating using apple mail / MacOS,but works perfectly in MS Outlook / Windows. Have tried removing account and reinstating - still doesn't work.

What could be causing this, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What is the mail source ? like gmail ?

Comment: Is the mailbox showing, did you try synchronize ??

Comment: did you run the connection doctor ?

Comment: The mail account is on a a domain I control. I've also tried to make it work with different accounts, including a gmail account. None will connect. I have tried synchronising rebuilding, deleting and recreating. Also have run the Connection Doctor, which tells me that - no matter which account I try, that authentication is failing.

Comment: And the connection doctor LOGS will show you why is it failing